# C - Storing arrays

Tags: c, windows

So in C I wrote a program which stored a password and told you about the security status of your chosen password.

Everything worked out when I put %s instead of `"%c"` for an array in the

```
scanf(" %S or %C", &password);
```

Function.

Why is it working with %s and not with %c?

```
scanf(" %s\n", &password);

while(i<20)
{
    if(isupper(password[i]))
    {
       c = 1;
    }

    if(isdigit(password[i]))
    {
       a = 1;
    }

    if(password[i]=='$')
    {
       b = 1;
    }

    i++;
}


if( a==1 && b==1 && c==1)
{
   printf("Your password is great");
}
else
{
   printf("Your password sucks");
}
```

Comment: Show  a program that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Because it is supposed to work with `%s` and not with `%c`.

Comment: @DavisR5 How is password defined?

Answer (score 2):

%s is for strings(multiple characters) example: "Hello"
%c is for one single character example: "H"